# gnome-terminator: Unable to access preferences window

Tags: gnome-terminator

I am able to start terminator 1.92 on a Red Hat 8 server.
The main window opens, then I right click Preferences;
**the preferences window does not open**.
Instead this message is produced in the original Terminal:

```
 Failed to find preferences.glade
'ascii' codec can't decide byte 0xe2 in position 35581: ordinal not in range(128)
```

More info
Don't think Terminator is reading the ~/.config/terminator/config file.
Tried adding the line
`Font = Fixed 20`
as an oblivious change from the default then restarting Terminator.
The font size did not change from the default.

Terminator was installed by the network admin for all users.

Comment: Ask or Tell your admin to set the locale properly.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10561923/unicodedecodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-decode-byte-0xef-in-position-1).

Comment: @eyeyourg100 echo $LANG produces en_US.UTF-8 for me.  Is that the right thing?

Comment: That is the correct LC setting.  What happens if you download version 1.9.2 from [GitHub Releases](https://github.com/gnome-terminator/terminator/releases) and [install manually](https://github.com/gnome-terminator/terminator/blob/master/INSTALL.md)

Comment: @eyoung I noticed there are some newer versions there also.   Anything special about 1.9.2?

Comment: No, we're trying to mimic what your admin did.  If you can install the same version he did, without error then it was installed incorrectly.  If you install it and the issue in your question repeats, then we have two options: 1) Upgrade the version as you suggested, or 2.) Install or fix a package or config change on the RedHat Enterprise.  Since the locale was set correctly. something else is amiss if the error repeats.